# ACF url field into button

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom field for Post type which I want to show up in the loop which I managed to do with the help of Advanced posts of Ultimate add-on for beaver builder. Now I want the link to be embedded in a button so that users may click the button and it open ups the value under url custom field.
Since I do not prefer core php method for greater control over my web content hence want to know if there is anyway around in html, bootstrap or shortcode to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting up a Link field, and following the examples from ACF, pass the `$link_url` into the anchor's href, `<a href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>">click here</a>` . Source: [ACF | Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/)

Here's the code they recommend using, which is of the same format that I generally use:

```
<?php 

$link = get_field('link');

if( $link ): 
    $link_url = $link['url'];
    $link_title = $link['title'];
    $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you're using the fields within a Repeater or a Group, use `get_sub_field()` instead of `get_field()`.